# Change db credentials while login in websphere

Tags: java, database, websphere, credentials

I have an application hosted on  IBM Websphere and WebSeal as proxy server.

I need to change the database password, but I`m not sure how can I configure the new db credentials in the web server so that the application can access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Database credentials for relational databases connected to WebSphere app server via a JDBC driver are configured and managed via one or more DataSources and JDBCProviders.   Start with [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_tccrtprovds.html).  The credentials are properties of the DataSource.